# What is the error in the code? It doesn't print the last terms in the first, third, fifth... lines

Tags: java

What is the error in the code? It doesn't print the last terms in the first, third, fifth... lines.

```
public class Pattern {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i = 1;
        for(i = 1; i<5; i++) {
            for(int j =i*i/2 - i/2 + 1; j < i*i/2 + i/2 +1 ; j++) {
                System.out.print(j + "\t");
            }   
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the current output? What were you expecting? What are you trying to do?

Comment: what output do you expect?

Comment: 7,8,9, and 10 are still less than 11 - this is the check in your method. That's why there is no linebreak. But what do you want to achieve? Probably, it can be made easier?

Answer (score 1):

For `i = 1`, the algorithm gives:

```
i * i / 2 = 1 * 1 / 2 = 0.5
```

as i is an Integer, the actual value is 0.

Same with all other odd numbers as 3 and 5.

Either use a double and round up or change your math.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - there is gonna be just 4 lines, not 5. Another thing, last 'term' doesn't print because of dividing integers. Like 1/2 will return 0, not 1.

Answer (score 0):

Run this code to see whats happening in for loop

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int i = 1;      
        for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
             int throughLoop = 0;
             int jInitial = i * i / 2 - i / 2 + 1;
             int jCheck = i * i / 2 + i / 2 + 1;
            for (int j =jInitial ; j < jCheck; j++) {
                System.out.print(j + "\t");
                throughLoop++;
            }
            //jInitial - jCheck because check is less than not less or equal
            System.out.println("Expected times through loop is " + (jCheck - jInitial) + " Actual through loop " + throughLoop+ " Check was :less than" +jCheck);
            throughLoop = 0;
        }

    }
```

---

Like somebody asked you what is the expected outcome. It might be that you need less than or equal compare not just less than `for(int j =i*i/2 - i/2 + 1; j <= i*i/2 + i/2 +1 ; j++)` but that's just me guessing without knowing what is it that you expect the output to be.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public class Pattern {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    float i = 1;
    for(i = 1; i<=5; i++) {
        for(float j =((i*i/2) - i/2 + 1); j < ((i*i/2) + i/2 +1) ; j++) {
            System.out.print((int)j + "\t");
        }   
        System.out.println();
    }
}

}
```

You were trying to print integer value from decimal points which is only possible with float.

Comment: And you were not using = sign before i assigning to 5,so it was only iterating 4 times.